# iOS Unit testing universal application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

I am trying to set up some unit tests on a universal application. The application behaves quite differently when loaded on ipad/iphone. For example there is a separate delegate for each, separate views and controllers as well.

How can I configure a particular test target or particular test files to be tested on iphone/ipad. For example, run TestsTarget1 on iPhone and TestTarget2 on iPad? Can something like this be set on a per-file basis? For example "TestIpadMaps.m" to be run on iPad while "TestIphoneMaps.m" to be run on iphone.

Edit: The reason why I ask is because I want to run tests on certain methods that make reference to the app delegate which is different depending on the device it is being tested on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if statement to check if NS (or it could be UI as I'm on my iPad so I don't have reference)device is equal to iPhone and if it is run your test or GoTo your view.

Here is a video that will help

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meiv1ePUEnM