# Target individual XCTest unit test cases in Xcode 5 to a specific iOS device for a universal app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unit-testing, xcode5

I'm building a universal iPhone/iPad application, and the UI is significantly different in some cases (i.e. on iPhone we use a Master/Detail paradigm with TableViews, whereas on iPad we're using a CollectionView with cells that contain the details).

Because the interfaces are so different, it changes how the unit tests for the view controllers are constructed. In the collection view, we'd have to test to make sure the cells get built correctly and contain all the detailed information, whereas on iPhone we'd need two sets of tests - one for the master list and one for the detail screen.

So my question is, in a universal application being built using Xcode 5 with XCTest framework, can you target individual unit test cases / classes to be run on specific **physical** devices?

I came across a similar question here - [iOS Unit testing universal application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134046/ios-unit-testing-universal-application) - but the asker had different intentions and was using older technologies.

I've also seen recommendations to do a check in individual test functions for **UserInterfaceIdiom** but that seems really crude. Ideally, there would be an annotation that would designate specific tests run on specific devices, or be able to designate an entire test class for a specific device.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

--EDIT--

@TommieC led me down what seems to be the appropriate path, if a smidge manual. I created two new testing specific schemes, one for phone-sized devices, and one for tablet-sized devices. Inside those schemes, I edited the test portion and added in the core tests along with the device-specific tests.

I then have jenkins execute two build steps, targeting the appropriate devices to test for the particular scheme. The downside to this approach is two build steps. However, I plan to split up the jenkins job and run it on 2 slaves with the appropriate devices hooked to each to parallelize the testing.

AFAIK this will also be Xcode Build Services friendly, as it works based off of schemes in a project as well. It's really too bad there isn't something more elegant built into XCTest for this, considering this doesn't scale terribly well in the event a new device type comes into play (watch/tv/hair dryer/etc.)

Comment: If you are against `UserInterfaceIdiom` have you considered splitting the iPad/iPhone discrete tests into their own test class and setting up another target? That way on the iPhone target you can exclude iPad tests.

Comment: I'm not against using it if it's the only solution. It's kind of ugly though for splitting up test cases where you should be able to do it at the file level.... plus it feels wrong to reference a user interface in a unit test in my opinion :)

Comment: That's a fair comment. To be honest the only time I've used `UserInterfaceIdiom` in a unit test is to figure out which Storyboard to load based on the idiom.

Comment: @squarefrog you shouldn't need to do that either - [NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] should do that for you automagically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To target device specific tests one would need to edit the schemes for a project. Under Product > Scheme > Edit Schemes one can choose to select device specific tests per device.

[image: Scheme Editor]

Comment: Hmmm this is only if you want to run on simulators, correct? When I said "devices" i meant physical devices - will update my question.

Comment: @MattS Actually I believe this applies to devices as well. I did not have mine loaded but see the top of the list.

Comment: That list isn't per test, that's per scheme. If you set it to one, that scheme's Test mode will run using that configuration. Edit - thinking that over though, you could create individual schemes to use for testing.

Comment: @MattS. Yes, and the scheme can be organized against specific devices, which seems to be what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: Accepting your answer because it led me down the correct path. I'll update my question with what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Heres my proposed solution.

Split your tests up into iPhone specific and iPad specific tests.

Now add a new Target (Cocoa Touch Unit Testing Bundle) specifically for iPhone or iPad. If you already have many common tests written, it may be more prudent to duplicate your current test target.

Now ensure that your iPhone specific test classes are only included in your iPhone test target by clicking on the class in the Navigator, and then open up the Utilities panel. You can set which target your class is a member of by using the Target Membership check boxes.

[image: Target Membership panel]

To expand on this you can add different schemes for your two targets to make running the tests quicker.

Comment: Hmmm an interesting idea. I'll give it a whirl and see how it integrates with Jenkins and report back.

Comment: Ended up picking the other answer, even though the end product is really a combination of both answers - separate testing targets vs separate schemes is really I think up to the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do this same thing and came across this old post. My solution involves naming specific device tests to end in either "Pad" or "Phone" and then filtering the list of tests to include the current device's tests:

```
class MyTests: XCTestCase {
    override class var defaultTestSuite: XCTestSuite {
        let suite = XCTestSuite(forTestCaseClass: MyTests.self)

        let newSuite = XCTestSuite(name: "MyTests")
        for test in suite.tests {
            // Name is of the form "-[MyTests test*]"
            if test.name.hasSuffix("Pad]") {
                // iPad only test
                if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                    newSuite.addTest(test)
                }
            }
            else if test.name.hasSuffix("Phone]") {
                // iPhone only test
                if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
                    newSuite.addTest(test)
                }
            }
            else {
                // Can run on both devices
                newSuite.addTest(test)
            }
        }

        return newSuite
    }

    func testAll() { // All devices test }
    func testOnlyPad() { // iPad only test }
    func testOnlyPhone() { // iPhone only test }
}
```